# Laravel cashier do not set trial and ends date

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I've just update my project to Laravel 5.2 and Cashier 6.0.
I've followed the documentation and added the new `subscriptions` table but when I test it Cashier do not set the trial ends column.

In my stripe plan I have 14 days of trial and in my stripe account I can see that if I add today a new costumer the first billing is set 14 days after.

This is my subscription code:

```
// Create the user
$user = $this->create( $request->all() );

// Find the plan in the DB
$plan = Plan::find( $request->get( 'plan' ) );

// Charge the user ( 14 days trial )
$user->newSubscription( $plan->slug , $plan->stripe_id )->create( $request->get( 'stripeToken' ), 
[
     'email'       => $request->get( 'email' ),
     'description' => ''
] );
```

The `$plan->slug` is the name I have associated to my plan, for example `annual` while the `$plan->stripe_id` is the same I have set on Stripe dashboard.

If I register a new customer all but `trials_ends_at` and `ands_at` are set.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out by myself.
The new Casher code needs to set manually the trial period with:

```
trialDays($trialDays)
```

So my code should be:

```
$user->newSubscription( $plan->slug , $plan->stripe_id )->trialDays(14)->create( $request->get( 'stripeToken' ), 
[
     'email'       => $request->get( 'email' ),
     'description' => ''
] );
```